# SOLVED: Problem with attribute routing in symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There's a solution via RFE for this in [RFE; solve problem with bin commands and php versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73509206/rfe-solve-problem-with-bin-commands-and-php-versions)

I'm dealing with a new app in symfony 5.4 and php 7.4 to test the new additions and changes in symfony 6. I've used the entity maker from the console to create the entity and the crud, and the db was created perfectly. However, the generator uses the new "attributes" (according to the convention in https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/routing.html) instead of the "classic" annotations. Debugging via console to see the resulting paths, none of the routes defined in the controllers is shown (of course, a 404 error was shown when accessing the url in dev mode). I decided to replace the attributes with classic annotations, and the paths are shown and the 404 error is gone. But now, I find that the logic the generator uses is via the repository to use the Entity Manager, and when accessing to the index to start from scratch, I get:

```
Could not find the entity manager for class "App\Entity\Room". Check your Doctrine configuration to make sure it is configured to load this entity’s metadata.
```

The portion of code shown in the debugger is this:

```
class RoomRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Room::class);  // Here is the error
    }
```

And the entity starts with this:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RoomRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: RoomRepository::class)]
class Room
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column()]
    private ?int $id = null;

...
```

My biggest concern is that I guess I can't rewrite the full crud reverting to annotations, which is a lot of work (just what I wanted to avoid by using the generator), so there must be something about the attributes that I'm missing. Here's a controller whose crud I haven't modified yet, so anyone can take a look and find out why the router can't find the defined paths with this kind of annotation.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\RoomFeature;
use App\Form\RoomFeatureType;
use App\Repository\RoomFeatureRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/admin/feature')]
class RoomFeatureController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'admin_room_feature_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(RoomFeatureRepository $roomFeatureRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('room_feature/index.html.twig', [
            'room_features' => $roomFeatureRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }

...
```

What is the problem with all this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So which generator are you using and you absolutely sure that the generator was run under 7.4 and not 8.x?

Comment: Well, regardless that bin/console make:crud was run under one version or another of php, I think the point is that, according to the docs, the resulting code using annotations via attributes should be compatible with whatever version of php is supported with symfony 5.4. If this assumption is wrong, it's a bug or whatever, please let me know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Correct, attributes should work just fine with an up to date version of Symfony 5.4 in conjunction with PHP 7.4. Just trying to understand how you got where you are. I was under the impression that the maker commands would generate annotations when PHP 7.4 was installed.  Consider creating a new 5.4 app and then run make:controller and see if the generated controller uses attributes or annotations. Then verify the controller works as expected.

Comment: And maybe look in your config/routing files and see if the src/Controller resource is of type annotation or attribute.  Having the wrong type would explain why your controller routes are not being picked up.

Comment: Yes, in config/routing/annotations.yaml it says "annotations". However, in config/packages/sensio_framework_extra.yaml it says annotations:false. Now, there are some questions: is there a bug in make:crud if the annotation type is ignored? Can both types of annotation be somehow mixed? Should one stick to one of both types, and maybe the future is that attributes replace annotations?

Comment: Also, for whatever it may concern, I made sure to create the .php-version file, so the symfony cli could start the server correctly. Should bin/console take a look at .php-version if not being run with an specific version of php?

Comment: Sorry for extending the discussion. I reviewed the docs and my concerns about php versions are solved, but it seems there's something not working, since the doc says "This configuration tells Symfony to look for routes defined as annotations/attributes in any PHP class stored in the src/Controller/ directory.". My config file is exactly as described in the doc, so attributes should work straight forward. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the first comment, forcing every bin/console (for make: commnds) and composer commands to be run **especifically** by prepending php7.4 to the command, everything works but with "classic" annotations, I've found no way to use attributes in controllers with php7.4. The .php-version file seems to be used only by the symfony-cli to launch the dev webserver. I hope this helps anyone who can face this scenario in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and on my case it was related to an incorrect namespace on a Trait (under src/Entity/Traits).

The trait wasn't even being used but apparently it will still cause this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second comment:

> the resulting code using annotations via attributes should be
> compatible with whatever version of php is supported with symfony 5.4

This assumption is wrong, since symfony 5.4 supports php 7.2.5 and up. Although 7.2 is sunsetted officially, there are plenty of installations out there or with extended support from distros so that's besides the point: Symfony will happilly run in 7.2 or 7.3.

In any case, it's maker bundle who determines whether or not to use attributes based on the php version that is used **to execute** the maker commands, not the available installed versions. You can force it to use specific version features by executing `composer config platform.php 7.4.x`.

And be aware that maker bundle 1.44 has dropped annotation support altogether, so pin your version to an older one.